# Calculating XIRR by using cash flows present in different ms excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cash inflow and outflow in different Excel sheets. Does anyone know how to calculate XIRR (using excel formula) in this situation?

Please, let me know, the solution without VBA.

Example: Sheet1: (Table5)

```
Fund, Order_Date, Invested_Amt 
Fund1, 1-Jun-17, 2500 
Fund2, 12-Dec-17, 1000 
Fund3, 5-Jun-18, 500 
Fund3, 8-Jan-20, 4000 
Fund1, 15-Aug-18, 5000 
Fund2, 10-Sep-20, 1000 
Fund1, 1-Jan-21, 300 
...so on and so forth
```

Sheet2: (We can take sell_date as today)

```
Fund, Sell_Date, Sold_Amt 
Fund1, 12-Jul-21, -10000 
Fund2, 12-Jul-21, -10000 
Fund3, 12-Jul-21, -5000
```

As of now, I came up with the below formula which is giving wrong answer:
`=XIRR(IF(Table5[Fund]=Sheet2!A2,Table5[Invested_Amt],0)+Sheet2!C2,Table5[Order_Date]+Sheet2!B2)`

I tried with 'choose' as well, but the list of cash inflows is big, due that the formula is becoming complex.

Comment: Well, now you have edited your question by removing the requirement for vba no you are not missing something. I do find the way you suggest I am incorrect with my original comment without you mentioning your edit is a little below the belt. However, a question so similar to this was posted yesterday - but I cannot find it, is this a "delete and repeat"?

Comment: Yes, I didnt included the way I tried to solve it.  So, someone closed the question and I couldnt make any changes to it.